# SonarQube Python Plugin - scanning python code: Fail to decorate

Tags: python, python-2.7, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to run a scan in the sample project (I am actually trying to scan a much larger project, but the problem is the same. I am working on the sample project because is much simpler) and it is giving me the following error:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 29.790s
Final Memory: 14M/379M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@56ffc188[key=src/__init__.py,deprecatedKey=__init__.py,path=src/__init__.py,dir=[root],filename=__init__.py,language=Python]'
ERROR: Caused by: 0
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Anyone has any idea of what this means? This is the sample project right out of the box, and my sonnar runner config is firly simple:

```
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Default source code encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#----- Security (when 'sonar.forceAuthentication' is set to 'true')
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
```

I have enabled all pylint rules, within a new profile just with those rules. With the default profile as default (Sonar Way) the error does not happen. Curious thing is that I enabled a random rule from pylint and it worked. So maybe one (or more) rule is messing with the analysis.

Pylint integration is essential for me.

The stacktrace, although not very helpful is the following:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@3f3674b2[key=src/__init__.py,deprecatedKey=__init__.py,path=src/__init__.py,dir=[root],filename=__init__.py,language=Python]'
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:103)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:86)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:126)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.tracking.FileHashes.getHash(FileHashes.java:75)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTracking.setChecksumOnNewIssues(IssueTracking.java:69)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTracking.track(IssueTracking.java:54)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator.doDecorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:138)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator.decorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:112)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:95)
        ... 36 more
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like the issue tracking algorithm fails to find line 0 of your ``__init__.py``, is it an empty file? Also, did you manage to pinpoint which Pylint rule makes the analysis fail?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I had to deactivate two rules to stop this error message:

- Missing docstring
- docstring should be defined

I also deactivate the deprecated rules but I don't know if it had any effect.